# Microsoft Access Join - Multivalued data

Tags: c#, ms-access, join, many-to-many, left-join

I am new to Access and am currently working on a project that has a database containing 3 tables : One with Personal data of employees, second with their education details, and 3rd with their occupation. All three have a common EMP_ID as their common connector. I made a left join between the first two tables to associate the education degrees to the respective employees. Since many employees hold more than one degree, I now have multiple entries for the same employee like the following:

EMP_ID Name       Age Gender Degree   University

1. John Doe   32     M     BE      ABC University
2. John Doe   32    M      MS      XYZ University
3. Jane Miller29    F     BE       PWQ University
4. Person3    45    F     BTech   MNB University

The first table consists of the first 4 rows of the above query result and the second table has the last two rows with the EMP_ID of the result.

I wanted to know if there was a way in which I could combine these multiple values and make them one single record, because if I have to JOIN the Occupation table (which contains multiple records for each EMP_ID), I would end up having a lot more than one record per person. I have to take this data and use it in a C# program. Would anyone have an idea of how to go about this? Or is there a better solution that I can follow!
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Without understanding more about how you want the data to appear, I can suggest putting the result of your query into a C# datatable, looping through each row and extracting/manipulating the data as needed. If you explain just what is desired, perhaps someone can suggest something else.

Comment: I actually wanted it to be more like a multi valued element. I wanted it to read 
1 || John Doe || 32 || M || BE || ABC University, XYZUniversity.

Comment: In that case, simply use separate datatables for each Access table, loop and concatenate.